# Would changing the geometry of the container of gas change the results of kinetic gas theory?

Tags: kinetic-theory

One of the predictions of Kinetic gas theory is that kinetic energy is a function of temperature but does this conclusion hold for geometries other than a cube?

I say cube because if you see the derivation of kinetic gas formula, it is done for a cube container considering the collisions w.r.t the container walls. If it is incorrect conceptually to extrapolate the cube case to other geometries, would it still hold as a good approximation?

---

[Proof of kinetic gas theory in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases)

Problematic steps in the above proof: In one of the steps, after considering the average velocity, the force is given as:

$$F = \frac{Nm \bar{v}^2 }{3L}$$

Where $L$ is length of the cube container,v is average velocity, N is number of molecules, L is length of container

Now for pressure:

$$P = \frac{ \frac{Nm \bar{v}^2}{3L}}{L^2}$$

Then it is aid that $\frac{1}{L^3}=V$, there are two problems iwth this when we consider geometries other than a cube.

1. The $L^2$ is not generally the area element of a shape, eg: for a cylindrical surface it is $r d \theta dz$
2. $ \frac{1}{L^3}$ is not generally the volume of a general 3-d shape.

This is the most glaring differences to me but there are probably more as well.

Comment: Why would you expect otherwise?  that is, what points in the proof would fail (not just get more complicated) if the container were a duodecagon or a sphere, e.g.?

Comment: Just a thought, but can one not take any arbitrary geometry and approximate it by a bunch of cubes, albeit infinitely small near curved surfaces.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft but how do I know this proof won't fail? There were no explanations to why it won't in the proof itself?

Comment: @BobD wouldn't these infinitesimal cubes have a lot of imaginary walls that the gas molecules bounce off of to return to hit the opposite side  of the cube( which is the small nearly curved surface)?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft pls see my edit , I've added an explicit step in the proof to address your comment

Comment: The derivation on Wikipedia is intentially simplified. More elaborate derivations do not need to assume the geometry (I guess this is technically an answer but I don't want to typeset a chapter of kinetic theory.)

Comment: @napstablook I don't understand what you are getting at.

Comment: The original equation involves the molecule first hitting 1 side of the cube and then return to that side after hitting the opposite side of the cube (which accounts for time taken between successive collisions to a wall). now if we were to place infinitesimal cubes on the surface of(let's say the lateral part of a cylinder) then wouldn't our molecules be hitting imaginary opposite sides of these small cubes? @BobD

Comment: Basically I don't get the details of how this generalization would work.

Comment: @napstablook Imagine a cube with real walls was introduced into the volume of arbitrary shape.  Would you expect the pressure in that cube to be different than the pressure outside the cube?

Comment: @jacob1729 please add a reference. All highschool text books only use this derivation so it's kind of confusing.

Comment: It is an experimental fact that pressure does not change with the shape of the container, thus you can use any convenient shape to do the calculation